# Customising the result of the query as per the business requirement via alias not working in Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms, ansi-sql

Oracle database is case insensitive and thus if I put any alias also the column name is always in capital letters. For e.g. If I run the following query:

```
Select ID as Id, AGE as Age, NAME as Name from Employee;
```

The result set columns would be like as follows:

```
ID | AGE | NAME
----------------
```

but I want them to be like as follows:

```
Id | Age | Name
-----------------
```

Is there any work around to achieve the same?

Comment: Use _delimited identifiers_, e.g. `"Id"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use double quotes to get an exact match:

```
Select ID as "Id", AGE as "Age", NAME as "Name"
from Employee;
```